# What is the performance overhead of hundreds of rxJS streams triggering dozens of times a second?

Tags: performance, rxjs

Does anyone have an estimate of what would be the performance overhead of using rxjs streams instead of events? An application that will have a couple of hundred streams that at peak will trigger at ~40Hz is too much? The performance should be about the same as with events, right? Or do the Observables, Observers, Disposables, etc. that make up the streams have too big of a footprint for this kind of use case?

Comment: that is an interesting question, but one it seems you can answer by yourself. I mean what prevents you for doing the simulation and posting the results here? That would make the question more attractive to other users and induce them to post their own results

Comment: I will surely need to do this; but you know what they say, sometimes the question is as important as the answer :)